# Passing Context of Service to an Activity

Tags: java, android

So I got a service (which is an InputMethodService to be exact) and this service starts an activity on a button click. The activity has a commitText() in it such that a text gets printed into the chatbox from where the hatbox got started initially. Now I don't get any output and I think the Context the Activity uses is another one from the Context the Service uses.

How do I change the context of the Activity to the Context of the Service?

Comment: How can you start an activity from service? And how you added button to service? Unclear question for me

Comment: I wanted to implement a keyboard. With creating an Intent and startActivity(). no need to downvote

Comment: the `Context` of `Activity` is assigned when it is created by the system and cannot be changed afterwards - see the sources of `android.content.ContextWrapper`

Comment: Hmm I think I don't really need to change it. just start the Activity given a provided context?

Comment: @craft Service is a Context by self. You don't need to retrieve it from Activity. You can run Activity directly from Service.

Comment: I do that, but then being in the activity I would like to access the InputConnection (to put something out in the chatbox) from the service which I can't reach being in the Activity